Flatten mapped type to intersection removing the iterated union' keys used to create it
I am not sure how to better phrase the question but I hope the question title with the code below is self-explanatory, despite it might seem useless.
EDIT reduced code to the bare minimum:
type MyUnion = "a" | "b";

type Result = {
  [K in MyUnion]: Record<`${K}_1`, { v: `${K}_2` }>;
};
// type Result = { a: Record<"a_1", { v: "a_2"; }>; b: Record<"b_1", { v: "b_2"; }>; };
type DesiredResult = { "a_1": { v: "a_2" }; "b_1": { v: "b_2" }; };

I don't understand how to get DesiredResult from Result

What's the input, MyUnion or Result? What are we allowed to modify? ... If I start with MyUnion I'd use key remapping to get DesiredResult as shown in this playground link. Or do you want us to start with Result and flatten it to DesiredResult as shown in this playground link?

the second link with that Flatten type works wonderfully @jcalz thanks! But I think I found what had caused me troubles in not getting there, it's about a need I found to double assert that flattened type in my array reduce implementation, I tried to show it in this playground link.

That's a followup question, isn't it? So it's out of scope here. I could write up the answer for Flatten here and then you can ask again elsewhere or find the answer elsewhere. From my brief glance there I'd say your create() function is incorrectly typed, when T is a union it claims to return something it doesn't. You could distribute over T like const create = <T extends string>(t: T) => ({ [\${t}1`]: `${t}2` }) as T extends any ? Record<`${T}1`, `${T}2`> : never;but again, this is out of scope here. I'll write upFlatten` when I get a chance.

Yes this was a follow up but it was what made me think my pre-Stack-Overflow attempts to flatten Result were failing, because without that double assertion I was just not getting the right type despite how I was flattening the Result mapped type. Anyway that T extends any ? Record<${T}1, ${T}2> : never; did the trick, fantastic @jcalz. Thanks a lot for your help!

You're looking for Flatten<T> to effectively become the intersection of all the properties of T.  We can do that by using a technique much like UnionToIntersection as shown in Transform union type to intersection type, where we put the types to intersect in a contravariant position (see Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript) and infer a single type for it:
type Flatten<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K]) => void } extends
    Record<keyof T, (x: infer I) => void> ? I : never;

That turns, say, {a: {x: string}, b: {y: number}, c: {z: boolean}} into {x: string} & {y: number} & {z: boolean}.  If you don't want to see a big intersection, you could use an identity-like mapped type to combine the intersection into a single object type:
type Flatten<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K]) => void } extends
    Record<keyof T, (x: infer I) => void> ? { [K in keyof I]: I[K] } : never;

Now you'd get {x: string; y: number; z: boolean}.
Let's test it:
type Result = {
    a: Record<"a_1", {
        v: "a_2";
    }>;
    b: Record<"b_1", {
        v: "b_2";
    }>;
}

type DesiredResult = Flatten<Result>;
/* type DesiredResult = {
    a_1: {
        v: "a_2";
    };
    b_1: {
        v: "b_2";
    };
} */

Looks good.

Note that you could use UnionToIntersection directly and write
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (x: U) => void : never) extends
    ((x: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type Flatten<T extends object> = UnionToIntersection<T[keyof T]>

and get effectively the same type
type DesiredResult = Flatten<Result>;
/* type DesiredResult = Record<"a_1", { v: "a_2"; }> & Record<"b_1", { v: "b_2"; }> */

but if any of your type's properties are themselves unions you'd end up intersecting them too, which I don't think you want. That is, the desired output of
type X = Flatten<{ a: { x: string } | { y: number }, b: { z: boolean } }>;

looks like
/* type X = { x: string; z: boolean; } | { y: number; z: boolean; } */

but using UnionToIntersection gives you
/* type X = { x: string; } & { y: number; } & { z: boolean; } */

Playground link to code
